# Having two websites use the same WordPress database to create a mobile version

Tags: html, wordpress, mobile

I want to create a mobile version of my website and host the WordPress install on a subdomain. For example, my main domain is at `http://www.startingtofeelit.com` and I linked the subfolder "mobile" to the subdomain `m.startingtofeelit.com`

I installed a fresh copy of WordPress to this folder/subdomain, and I want whatever posts appear on my main domain to appear here as well. I copied/pasted the wp-config.php file over to the mobile domain so it would link to the correct database, but using functions like `the_permalink()`, or trying to log in, always return values from http://www.startingtofeelit.com instead of the subdomain.

Is there an easy way to make a mobile subdomain work correctly in WordPress?

Comment: Recently I have been designing all sites to be responsive so that I do not have to maintain two sets of styles. I know it is not a specific answer to your question but check out http://getskeleton.com

Comment: Not really helpful, considering I want an entire new layout on mobile. Making it responsive is not what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't link to an authoritative resource, but I'm pretty sure that's not possible. Sharing the [same user table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Custom_User_and_Usermeta_Tables) is possible, but the whole site not.

But I think that's an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/185667). Instead you should serve your own theme when your selected devices hit the site.

Study how the plugin [WP Touch](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wptouch/) or similar do it. I know we need the hook [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect), which is the one I use in my plugins, when we want to override the Theme and serve a Plugin template.

Comment: I found a plugin that does this for me. Thanks for the suggestion.